# Want to fetch the records where subscription will expire in 5 days in mysql

Tags: mysql

Want to fetch the records where subscription will expire in 5 days in mysql .

**query using -**

```
select *
from tbl_users user
inner join tbl_purchase_plan plan on (user.cc_plan_option_id=plan.id)
where DATE_SUB( user.created, INTERVAL plan.plan_duration MONTH ) = (CURDATE() + INTERVAL  3 DAY)
  and user.status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from tbl_users user
inner join tbl_purchase_plan plan on (user.cc_plan_option_id=plan.id)
where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE_ADD( user.created, INTERVAL plan.plan_duration MONTH )) = 5
and user.status=1
```